# Change Text Input UI

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the UI of an Text Input field.

This is how the current **CSS** looks like:

```
textarea.form-textarea-user-name {
    width:              110px;
    height:             80px;
    text-transform:     uppercase;
    resize:             none;
    font-size:          18px;
}
```

And this is how the **SCRIPT** looks like:

```
function getSelectionInformationHtml(selectionId, userName, selectionText)
{
    var selectionIdAsId = selectionId.replace(/^[^a-z]+|[^\w]+/gi, '_');
    var text = '<form name="selection-update-' + selectionIdAsId + '" onsubmit="sendSelectionInformation(\'' + selectionId + '\'); return false;">';
    text += '<span class="selectionId">' + selectionId.substring(0, selectionId.lastIndexOf(" ")) + ':</span> <textarea class="form-textarea-user-name" rows="1" cols="20" placeholder="your name">' + userName + '</textarea><textarea class="form-textarea-selection-text" rows="1" cols="50" placeholder="the new message">' + selectionText + '</textarea><button type="submit">Save</button>';
    text += '</form>';
    return text;
}
```

This is how I want the new Text Input to look lik:

https://codepen.io/PRtheRose/pen/BNgEJo

My **question**:
Where and how do I place this HTML in my Script

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="demo-flex-spacer"></div>

  <div class="webflow-style-input">
    <input class="" type="email" placeholder="What's your email?"></input>
    <button type="submit"><i class="icon ion-android-arrow-forward"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="demo-flex-spacer"></div>
  <h1 class="demo">Webflow-style input</h1>
  <a class="demo" href="https://webflow.com/cms" title="Webflow CMS">https://webflow.com/cms</a>

</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem here? You can copy over the same CSS from the codepen example, and then subsequently modify the `text` variable in your javascript to match the HTML from the codepen example. That should provide you with all you need?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zgb5cbqh/1/   what's the problem here? Your CSS is working with auto generated html. Just put all the css required to match that link text area.

Comment: I have tried several different ways. I must be doing it all wrong. Could you give me a little hint to get me going?

Comment: All we have to go in is what you tell us, and all of the code you have given is working so there is no problem there that we can help you with.

Comment: I am assuming that this is the string I would like to change:
 <textarea class="form-textarea-user-name" rows="1" cols="20" placeholder="your name". But this string wont accept any of the HTML from Codepen.

Comment: Maybe if you showed us the code that you actually want to change in your question we might be able to help.

Comment: I have added the code to the question